# Hyperbolic cylinder

Tags: geometry

I'm reading the first chapter of the book "[Geometry and spectra of compact Riemann surfaces](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9780817649913)" by P. Buser. On page 9, he wrote

> Parametrize $\gamma$ and $\gamma^\prime$ with unit speed and opposite boundary orientation such that $\gamma(0) = a$ and $\gamma^\prime(0) = b$.

Why is "opposite boundary orientation"? I though that it should be the same orientation according to the picture he gave. Did I misunderstand something here? 
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it **is** the opposite orientation as part of the boundary. A consistent orientation would be, say, the path through $a,$ then a line segment, then the path through $b$ backwards of the drawn arrow, then another line segment. Riemann surfaces are orientable, the interior of the bounded region should be thought of as having a little arrow indicating a direction of rotation.